# Select First Child List Item That has Children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following unordered list item with nested `ul`. How do I select the first `li` aka the text "List A" ?

I tried `ul > li:first-child` but this selects the first list item's child as well.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
        <li>
          List A
          <ul>
            <li>List A sub</li>
            <li>List A sub</li>
            <li>List A sub</li>
            <li>List A sub</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          List B
          <ul>
            <li>List B sub</li>
            <li>List B sub</li>
            <li>List B sub</li>
            <li>List B sub</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the parent of the outer `<ul>` to the selector, e.g. `body>ul>li:first-child` as right now you have 3 `<ul>`s with a `li:first-child` => 'List A', 'List A sub' and 'List B sub'

Comment: So let's say the list is inside div `.container`; you're saying I can do `.container > ul > li:first-child` ? Because I tried this and doesn't work either.

Comment: Don't quote me on this but I believe there's a `:has(.selector)` which returns the element before it only if the parametarised selector exists within it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set it up with the **default style** of `ul > li`.

```css
ul > li{
  font-weight: normal;
  color: gray;
}
.container > ul > li:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
        <li>
          List A
          <ul>
            <li>List A sub</li>
            <li>List A sub</li>
            <li>List A sub</li>
            <li>List A sub</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          List B
          <ul>
            <li>List B sub</li>
            <li>List B sub</li>
            <li>List B sub</li>
            <li>List B sub</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```